# Problems with newcommand based on liturg.sty

Tags: macros, italic

I have a brief document here and I have defined (based on the liturgy.sty package) a command called "rub". The issue I am having is that (and it does exactly what I want) text after the text inside the "rub" command also appears in italics.

How can I eliminate that?

Thanks,

-Michael D

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[left=1.75cm,
  right=1.75cm,
  top=1.95cm,
  bottom=2.50cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand\rub[1]{%
\noindent\normalsize\itshape\textcolor{red}{#1}\normalsize\textnormal\\%
}

\begin{document}

\rub{Then, we chant the Dismissal according to the Day of the Week. \footnote{A much abbreviated listing of daily commemorations is available in Appendix I}} 

Blah blah blah.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I "fiddled" with it for a bit and found at least one way of fixing it.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[left=1.75cm,
  right=1.75cm,
  top=1.95cm,
  bottom=2.50cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand\rub[1]{%
{\noindent\normalsize\itshape\textcolor{red}{#1}\normalsize}\\%
}

\begin{document}

\rub{Then, we chant the Dismissal according to the Day of the Week.         \footnote{A much abbreviated listing of daily commemorations is available in     Appendix I}} 

Blah blah blah.
```

\end{document}

And that is just to add an extra set of curly braces to the defined command!

-MD

Answer (score 1):

`\itshape` is a font switch: It changes everything after the command, within the current grouping, to the italic typeface. `\textit{}` is a font command, which limits the font to what is inside the braces (that is, the argument to the command. So use `\textit{}` or `\emph{}` and put the rest of the command inside the braces.

(Also, you probably don't need `\normalsize` at all, and this is not the best way to use `\\`)

```
\newcommand{\rub}[1]{%
    \noindent\textcolor{red}{\textit{#1}}\par
}
```